# How to Round the Index of a Data Frame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I can use DataFrame.apply(np.round) to round the entries of a data frame. However, I do not know how to apply it to the index.
Assuming that I have the following data frame:

```
    Index       A        B
    0.343       42       30
    0.5678      43       32
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
    Index       A        B
    0.3         42       30
    0.6         43       32
```

What would be the best solution for that?

Comment: You can cast the `index` type to series calling `to_series` and it's just the same op: `df.index = df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: np.round(x,2))`

Comment: Or `df.index = df.index.to_series().apply(lambda x: x.round(2))`

Comment: Works well, thanks! When I want to reindex the data frame, an error occurs: "cannot reindex from a duplicate axis". How can I drop the duplicates?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html